# react select removing the border and box shadow

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to override the css of the react select options div, so in the latest react-select v2, we can pass it as styles

```
 <Select
    styles={{
      option: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        border: null, // tried border: 'none'
        boxShadow: null, // tried border: 'none'
        outline: 0
      }),
    }}
  />;
```

i am trying to remove the border, tried with the above snippet but the border and the shadow remains same

also when click on select i need to override the blue color background on the time of click

how can i achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the border of the entire options list, then you need to set the style on the `menu` component and not on the `option` component.

Also, for overriding the style of the Select input component you need to set the style on `control` component

You can try doing this -

```
<Select
  styles={{
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      boxShadow: "none",
      border: state.isFocused && "none"
    }),
    menu: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      border: "none",
      boxShadow: "none"
    }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
       ...provided,
       backgroundColor: state.isFocused && "lightgray",
       color: state.isFocused && "red"
    })
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Here is the list of components to be used for setting styles in `react-select` - https://react-select.com/styles#style-object

Comment: Thanks Arpitha, Menu css worked, but when you click on option a blue css effect is applying how can i remove that one

Comment: You can add styling for `option` component when it is focused. I have updated my answer with a sample styling for `option` component.

Comment: @ Arpitha one doubt, in multi select when we select the input field have selected options is there a way where the options will get selected in the menu and options won't come inside the input box ?